# Disabling menu button in Android using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building my first mobile app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile, and I've run into a little issue.

I've been testing it on Android, both on a physical device and the emulator. As this application is very simple and has nothing much in the way of settings, I'd like to disable the Menu button.

Now, the impression I got from [the PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton) is that you need to add an event listener for the menubutton event in order to override the default behaviour, and use preventDefault to stop the default action taking place. Try as I might, I can't seem to get it to work. The code I've written for it is on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattBD/ZEYVN/3/).

Is this possible? If so, any idea where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Should really have mentioned the version - I'm using PhoneGap 2.0.

Comment: Hey @mattbd that code looks right. What behaviour are you getting when you click on the menu?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald The Settings dialogue pops up as usual. It looks like it gets called, because if I put an alert() in above e.preventDefault(), that works. Does the same on both the Android emulator and my phone, so it doesn't look like it's something device-specific,

Comment: Why are you providing a settings dialog if you don't want to see one?

Comment: I'm not providing one. As far as I can see it's there by default. It's a very simple application and I felt that the default Settings dialogue was superfluous.

Comment: I'm confused. On Android in order to get a menu you need to a) create an xml file that represents the menu b) implement a couple of Java methods to handle the display of the menu. Can you post a screen shot of what you are seeing? Or maybe the code from your main class that extends DroidGap?

Comment: I've basically just used http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android as a starting point, and everything else has been HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I haven't touched the XML or Java files beyond that

Comment: If you zip up your eclipse project I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Seems to be a new default in PhoneGap 2.0.

In the .java file under the src folder (MainActivity.java appears to be the default file name), comment out onCreateOptionsMenu function.

Comment: yes it works! This default menu is also there on phonegap 1.9. playing with the javascript event handler was not working at all.