# Disabling Android menu button in PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

When creating an Android app using *PhoneGap Build*, how can I prevent the system from adding the menu button at the bottom of the screen?

[image]

From [Disabling menu button in Android using PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003757/disabling-menu-button-in-android-using-phonegap), I got that when using pure *PhoneGap*, the solution appears to be to comment out the  `onCreateOptionsMenu` function in `MainActivity.java`. However, when using *PhoneGap Build*, I obviously do not have access to any java files.

So what is the solution for *PhoneGap Build*?

- Is there a special option that needs to be set in the config.xml?
- Can it be disabled via the JavaScript event handler for the menu button?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks! This has been bugging me for a long time now..

Answer (score 8):

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html mentions one solution that works for me:

> ...to ensure that the overflow action button never appears beside the system navigation, you should set the **targetSdkVersion** to **14**.

Note also that:

> ...you can leave **minSdkVersion** at something much **lower** to continue supporting older devices.

The above can be set in the **config.xml**.

Comment: This solves the problem for me. I'll leave the question here in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: I set targetSdkVersion to 11 and the menu button disappeared.

Comment: It also help me to turn off this button. To be precise, I place it: `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />` in config.xml