# Disable home and back buttons in android

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I'm doing an appication under phonegap (more specific in android). How can I disable the home, menu and back buttons in the screen, the idea is when i press any of the buttons, show a verification dialog, if the answer is correct, close the app. When i assign the function button doesn't show the dialog

Comment: Here are 2 posts that may help you: [Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791324/how-do-i-disable-android-back-button-on-one-page-and-change-to-exit-button-on-ev) and 
  [Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003757/disabling-menu-button-in-android-using-phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the home menu remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function and also you wouldn't need the `onOptionsItemSelected()` function, so to hide the menu remove these two.

For the back buttons there are two of them:

The hard button in device that navigates in the app until it hits the main activity then pops out of the app, can be controlled by overriding this method `onBackPressed()`

And the one in the action bar that navigates all inside the app itself but never pops the user out of the app, can be set by `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` which takes a Boolean `true` to make it working, `false` to disable it.